# Как сделать наследование на другую страницу из cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, облако, firestore

У меня есть страница на которой выводятся карточки, заполняемые из cloud firestore:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Items').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
              return GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                childAspectRatio:
                    (SizeConfig.itemWidth / SizeConfig.itemHeight),
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(snapshot.data.docs.length, (index) {
                    return buildItemCard(
                        context, snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                  })
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
```

как сделать, чтобы по клику на карточку выводилась инфа из карточки на другой странице (страница с описанием)?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас уже готова страница для детального описания, можно вызывать метод открытия страницы, передав параметр текущего элемента.

Например:

```
void showDetailPage() async {
    var result = await Navigator.push(
        this.context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => new CatalogItemPage(
                productRes: widget.productRes,
             ),
        ...
```

Вызов этого метода можно осуществить через обертку вокруг [GestureDetector](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/handling-taps).
В данном примере `productRes` содержит информацию, которая будет выводиться на странице.

[Подробнее](https://metanit.com/dart/tutorial/4.3.php) про наследование в dart.

Comment: В моем случае, элемент, информацию которого нужно отобразить на отдельной странице тоже является виджетом.